# Prevent (the average user) from downloading PDF

Tags: java, pdf, web

Before you all start your rants... I know already that whatever I do there will always be a way to download pictures and PDFs from a webpage.

But let's assume my users are not that tech savvy and only know the basics.

I've been asked to "disable" the download option when showing some images and PDFs in our webapp.

I managed to disable the context menu for the images with a single line of CSS but I am having trouble with the PDFs.

What I have tries so far:

1. With the  tag, move the element up to hide the toolbar. Worked OK for Firefox, then I discovered that other browsers just display the download button on hover
2. Cover the  element with a transparent div. Worked for FF and Chrome. Doesn't work with IE and Edge (the embed element is always put on top of the rest)
3. Same as two but with iFrame. IE doesn't show the iFrame at all when behind the
4. I've used SwingLabs PDF-renderer to convert the PDF to image. The end image colors are all wrong.

I have limited resources due to security restrictions and I'm running out of ideas. Any suggestions?

NOTE: The users able to see these PDF need to authenticate and have special permissions, so no worry about fiddling.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can tell you what they're for: The answer is: Tell your manager that what he wants simply doesn't work that way and that it simply doesn't work. If there's a legal reason behind it, then assuming an "average" user is a no go, because the law covers *all* situations.

Comment: This is a great question. I see this question a lot, you are not alone in getting this requirement. Do the users need to be able to "interact" with the PDF, such as selecting/searching for text? If not, then I would recommend generating images that are watermarked specifically to the user. So if they try to print or screenshot, their name and date is on it. If interaction is important, let me know and I will post an answer.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I like the watermark idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with the answers about the requirements being idiotic, there are ways around your problem. Namely, simply don't give the average user a PDF, but something else. And give the PDF to the privileged users. You already pointed out you have a way of telling them apart.

There are libraries you can use to convert from PDF to another format. I was once given a relatively similar assignment. Mine was to give a preview of a document before the user DL'd it and the client app opened the relevant word processing software.

While I can't in good conscience recommend Aspose libraries (I really didn't like working with this tool), they were what was in use in the company I worked for at the time, and I know they can do what you need to do. They are neither free as in free-speech, nor free as in free-beer, but they can be downloaded and tried free of charge, at the cost of a big watermark on the generated/converted documents.

I let Aspose do the work of converting the document to an HTML file, and loaded it in an iFrame in my interface.

If the solution of serving the PDF's contents in another format is not acceptable to your manager, you really need to let them know of their idiocy.

Comment: Dunno why my comment is gone... Yes, as also said in my question I tried to render the PDF as an image, so that is a valid solution. We just need to allow the admins to see the documents but they should not store them.

Answer (score -1):

> I've been asked to "disable" the download option when showing some images and PDFs in our webapp.

There's this thing called "Ethics" and "developer responsibility". This is one of the cases where you're not facing a technical problem, but a social one and there's only one solution: Go tell whoever did ask that from you that they are a moron and the web simply doesn't work that way. Especially with PDFs!

Did you ever open a PDF in a browser? Did you notice that ***all*** the browser built-in PDF viewers present a "save this PDF" button quite prominently in the toolbar? Do you realize, that the PDF viewer operates outside the context of your website and you can't manipulate it (for security reasons)?

*Seriously: The solution to this problem is to tell the person above you, that what they ask you to do is unreasonable and just breaks things. This is* your *responsibility to do!*

Comment: Thanks but this is just another useless rant. The manager doesn't care about the ethics or whatever. There is a legal requirement to prevent the download and I need a solution.

Comment: @algiogia: If there's a "legal" requirement, then you're f**** anyway, because __*everything*__ a browser displays is downloaded in the first place. And as I already explained, if it's a PDF the user will see a "Save As" button no matter what you do, because the PDF viewer runs outside the realms of your control. As a developer you *must* learn to speak up against your superiors if their demands are unreasonable and/or may jeopardize things. Your situation is tame and insignificant, but it's in the same line that led to the recent Boeing MCAS debacle.

Comment: Don't you think you are exaggerating things? There ARE ways around it. The PDF can be rendered in other ways that don't show the save button. I'm just asking for help with the implementation.

Comment: @algiogia Nah, not really exagerating. The PDF really is downloaded to a tmp folder on the user's client. The "Save as"/"Download" button is really just a copy+paste function from the tmp/ folder to the folder of your choice. Even if you managed to disable the button, one could still retrieve the document from the tmp/ folder.

Comment: Sorry but you two are fixating on the wrong bit. I've already said the PDFs can be rendered as something else. Also, the requirement is just to disable/not show the "save" option

Comment: @algiogia If rendering it as something else, check out my answer

Comment: So "prevent saving PDF" = "faulty airplane" 

Comment: @algiogia: More like "not speaking up against your superiors who demand stupid things = may create severe legal repercussions". You said that you musn't expose the PDFs for legal reasons. That's fair. But then you must assume the worst case scenario, which in your case is the PDF ending up in a temporary folder  (= Browser Cache), getting indexed by the operating systems's search database and thereby directly accessible to the user, through the operating system's document search function. You're trying to stop a sieve from leaking there.

Comment: @datenwolf yep, I know. I told them that it's actually not possible and they replied that hiding the obvious option to download was enough. The operators allowed to see the documents are in the internal network anyway. I haven't been given the full legal requirements but I suppose they are just being overzealous